# How to make a bot react to **only one** specific emoji?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm an absolute beginner just to mention it. So the bot should understand (shown as the message 'ThumbUp/ThumbDown') that the user has reacted to the already existing reaction. My problem is that if I react to one of the both reactions, both messages get send out, so I think I need to separate them somehow. Can anyone help me whith that?

```
  @client.event
        async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

            reaction == get(message.reactions, emoji='')
            if reaction.count > 1:
                    await message.channel.send('ThumbUp')
                    await helpmessage.delete()
            else:
                    await asyncio.sleep(30)
                    await helpmessage.delete()

            reaction == get(message.reactions, emoji='')
            if reaction.count > 1:
                    await message.channel.send('ThumbDown')
                    await helpmessage.delete()
            else:
                    await asyncio.sleep(30)
                    await helpmessage.delete()
```

Comment: not familiar with discord but did you try putting an additional ```=``` after the ```emoji``` in the get

Comment: then it gives out this error: ```NameError: name 'emoji' is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. Using else:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji='')
    if reaction.count > 1:
        await message.channel.send('ThumbUp')
    else:
        reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji='')
        if reaction.count > 1:
            await message.channel.send('ThumbDown')
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(30)

    await helpmessage.delete()
```

2. Using a dictionary:

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    checks = {'': 'ThumbUp', '': 'ThumbDown'}
    for emoji, msg in checks.items():
        reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
        if reaction.count > 1:
            await message.channel.send(msg)
            break
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)

    await helpmessage.delete()
```

Comment: I have tried both versions and both give me the same error: ```Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\EmoteBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/EmoteBot/main.py", line 42, in on_reaction_add
    if reaction.count > 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```
Doesn't that mean that there is some problem with the reaction and it needs to be defined or something?

Comment: You can replace all `if reaction.count > 1:` with `if reaction is not None and reaction.count > 1:` and see if it works.

Comment: At first there's no error, but no text send out either. But as soon as the message gets deleted, it sends out an error: ```Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 51, in on_reaction_add
    await helpmessage.delete()
  File "", line 1023, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Comment: I don't know where you're storing your `helpmessage` variable, but this error means that message represented by `helpmessage` does not exist (maybe it has already been deleted, you may want to add a try-except block around `await helpmessage.delete()`). Also, I can't see where you're storing the `message` variable. According to [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), if you want to get the message being reacted, you should use `reaction.message` instead of only `message`.

Comment: My ```helpmessage``` ist stored here: ```helpmessage = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)``` and afterwards there are only the reactions being added and the event, my question is about. So I've build in the try-except block like this 
```         try:
                await helpmessage.delete()
            except:
                helpmessage.content == None ```
Also I tried making the reactions  to ```reaction1``` and ```reaction2```, so they don't interact with each other somehow. But now I neither get send out a message, nor an error, still it deletes itself after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the fix is adding a second `=` in the line, where the `reaction` gets determined. So it is   `reaction == get(helpmessage.reactions, emoji="")`